# How does GibbsLDA++ ensure that we are sampling from a good posterior?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

This is an extending of this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103031/practical-implementation-of-gibbs-sampling-in-latent-dirichlet-allocation), which asked that whether we should do some estimating to ensure that we are really using a likely topic assignment instead of the one happened with low probability. And @Matt said that GibbsLDA++ was to do that, choose the last $T$ iterations instead of just the last one. I wonder is it related by the term $lag$ in MCMC? In addition, I downloaded the source code of GibbsLDA++, but I can't find that specific part to mark the parameter in last $T$ iterations and utilize it. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: I believe Matt's comment said that GibbsLDA++ does **not** let you choose the last $T$ iterations.

Comment: @Greenparker I am not sure what "this" means actually in his comments. Do you know which tool utilizes the last T iterations? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I am aware, none of the implementations utilize the last $T$ iterations. The R package `lda` outputs the average of the samples for $\theta$ indirectly using `document_expects`.

Comment: @Greenparker Could you please take a look on this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207522/how-to-determine-and-use-the-sampling-lag-in-the-collapsed-gibbs-sampler) that I newly opened to see whether I have a right understanding? Thanks!!